# Filtering a nested array in React with two search inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtering

I am having an issue with the logic in my filter. It works if I try try sort based off of the key pairs that are strings. For example if I set `var tagStr = student.company.toLowerCase().includes(tagQuery.toLowerCase());` I can search by name and company without any issues.

However my app breaks when I try to sort by name and tag using the code below.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

import StudentInfo from "./components/StudentInfo";

function App() {
    const [nameQuery, setNameQuery] = useState("");
    const [tagQuery, setTagQuery] = useState("");

    const data = "students": [
         { 
              "company": "Yadel",
              "firstName": "Ingaberg",
              "id": "1",
              "lastName": "Orton",
              "tags: [tag1, tag2]

         },{
              "company": "Tazzy",
              "firstName": "Skelly",
              "id": "20",
              "lastName": "Rydings"
              "tags: [tag1, tag2]
     ]

    return (
        <App>
            <Container id="input-container">
                <Row>
                    <input
                        onChange={(event) => setNameQuery(event.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Search by name"
                    ></input>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <input
                        onChange={(event) => setTagQuery(event.target.value)}
                        placeholder="Search by tag"
                    ></input>
                </Row>
            </Container>
            <Container id="result-container">
                {data
                    .filter((student) => {
                        var firstAndLastNameStr = (student.firstName + " " + student.lastName)
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .includes(nameQuery.toLowerCase());

                        var tagStr = student.company.toLowerCase().includes(tagQuery.toLowerCase());


                        if (nameQuery === "" && tagQuery === "") {
                            return student;
                        } else if (tagQuery === "" && firstAndLastNameStr) {
                            return student;
                        } else if (nameQuery === "" && tagStr) {
                            return student;
                        } else if (firstAndLastNameStr && tagStr) {
                            return student;
                        }
                    })
                    .map((student) => (
                        <StudentInfo
                            key={student.id}
                            index={student.index}
                            student={student}
                        ></StudentInfo>
                    ))}
            </Container>
        </App>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I know the issue is that `tags` is an array and I have tried using `.join()` to make it a string, but it still won't work. Can someone explain how I can solve this issue?

Comment: You have what seems to be a syntax error at `const data = "students": [...]`, is that a copy paste error maybe ?

Comment: Please [check the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). May I kindly highlight for your attention this line (from the docs): **callbackFn Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return a value that coerces to true to keep the element, or to false otherwise.**. Now, please consider what is being returned from `data.filter` in the above code.